# How to include stdout logs from python logging package in yarn logs (client mode)

Tags: python, logging, hadoop-yarn, python-logging

I have a python application in which I have a logger using python *logging* package. I'm running my job on the edge node using spark submit, **in client mode** (for now that's the only option).

I'm facing a problem to include stdout logs in yarn log file. Logs passed in the code to the logger (f.ex with `logger.info('I am here')` are only printed in console stdout, but are not included in yarn logs. I'm accessing yarn logs with `yarn logs -applicationId <ID>.`

I can see logs related to yarn, spark settings etc but no logs from logger. I was playing already with handlers, with log levels, at this point I'm running out of ideas. Is there anything that should be added in spark submit to include those logs? Is it maybe somehow due to running it in client mode? There is unfortunately not much info about connecting this logging package with yarn.

Thanks for all suggestions!

Here is how my logger definition looks like:

```
import logging

class Logger:
    def __init__(self, module_name='module_name'):

        self._py_logger = logging.getLogger(f'LOGGER_TEST: {module_name}')
        self._py_logger.setLevel('INFO')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s]: %(message)s')

        stream_handler = CustomStreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        if self._py_logger.hasHandlers():
            self._py_logger.handlers.clear()

        self._py_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    @property
    def get_logger(self):
        return self._py_logger
```